# Can I change the behavior of getClass().getName() method

Tags: java

I have a Class Foo.

```
Foo toy=new Foo("toy");

Foo shoe=new Foo("shoes");
```

can we do something so that

1 `toy.getClass().getName()` would print: `toy`.

2 `shoe.getClass().getName()` would print: `shoe`.

Comment: This seems a perfectly reasonable question to me, and it got my up-vote.

Answer (score 2):

No, not easily. [`Class#getName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--) is used for reflection and debugging and is part of the Java runtime. Since `java.lang.Class` is final, you wouldn't be able to override it (not that it matters, since `getClass()` returns a `Class` anyway and won't have anything to do with your subclass, even if you could make that happen)

Instead just use `toy.toString()` and add a toString method to the `Foo` class that outputs whatever value you passed into the constructor.

Comment: In addition the class `Class` is final which prevents any overriding.

Comment: @hotzst True, thanks. `getClass()` would still only return a `j.l.Class` anyway (never anything else, even if one managed to extend Class somehow)